# How to handle image path not found in Justified Gallery

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am creating images grid in asp.net and I am using the following library [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) . I am using `asp:Repeater` for the same and its working fine. but when any image path from the grid is not found then full grid is not displaying.
my code is

```
<div id="justifiedGallery">    
<asp:Repeater ID="DataListSearchResult"
                runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:ImageDetailWindowNew('<%#Eval("ItemId")%>')">
                            <img id="img1" style="opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);" onerror="imgError(this);" src="/IMAGES/<%#Eval("ImageFile")%>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <%#gettitlethumb(Eval("ImageTag"))%>
                        </div>                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
```

I am using a `Javascript` function to handle this but its not working.

```
 <script>
    function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/onerror.gif";
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Take a look on this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3gzh2sL/1/#&togetherjs=NsO72Mj3ag). In this fiddle I am using 3 images but the 2nd image path is incorrect and only two images are displaying.I don't want to hide the `Not displaying` image.

Please help me to create this. Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: @coder no not getting any error but the `Not found path images` visibility is getting hide

Comment: What is onError and whu u pass there empty string ?

Comment: @vivid I am not getting any error ...i just want to display a `not found` image on the images which is not not exist into the directory. but in Justified Gallery visibility of the  images which are not exist into the directory  getting hide.

Comment: In ur code u pass image.onerror = "" isnt that place where u should pass error handler ? Not sure

Comment: @vivid error handler  like ??

Comment: @vivid I am using this answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/4003331

Comment: ye it should do the trick :) tou could probably write image.onerror = ()=>{image.src = "/images/onerror.gif";}